# Spark: check if parquet write succeded

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark 1.6.2 (on Scala) process which writes a parquet file, and when it finishes, it should load it back again as a `DataFrame`. Is there a Spark method to check it a `DataFrameWriter` finished successfully and resume only after that? I've tried using `Future` and `on Complete`, but it doesn't work well with Spark (`SparkContext` gets shut down).

I assume I can just look for the `_SUCCESS` file in the folder and loop until it's there, but then if the process gets stuck, I'll have an infinite loop..

Comment: Isn't the writing of the data synchronous?

Comment: I'm not sure.. heard some issues about it, though it may have to be with Spark <-> S3 working together..